# where to find specific version of aws-java-sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jar, aws-java-sdk

I want to download aws-java-sdk-1.9.5, could not find any archive for this jar.
Whatever I am finding is the latest jar from AWS site https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/

I also checked maven repository but there the available jar is of 2 KBs only that didn't contain any source in the jar.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.9.5

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download from official [AWS Repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java).

Here is the [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/releases/tag/1.9.5) for version 1.9.5

Comment: Thank you Kush, It is a source code so I have built this code locally and again I got a jar that is 3 KBs of size. 
I am not sure how this 3 KBs jar will full fill all the requirements?

Comment: One can no speculate on code without going through it , your question was about downloading the the older version for aws sdk , update question or post new question with java tag if you have other concerns

Comment: I got the solution, I made assembly jar by updating pom.xml and then with the build, I got the executable jar.

Answer (score 0):

The `aws-sdk-java` JAR contains a list of dependencies on all other JARs in the AWS SDK. If you depend on it, then by Maven's [transitive dependency mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) you will add all of the other SDK JARs to your dependency tree.

**Which you *do not* want to do**

I've lost count of the number of individual AWS JARs, but there are a lot -- certainly dozens, possibly as many as a hundred. There's one JAR (at least) per AWS service, most of which you will never use.

A better approach is to download that JAR so that you know the names of the dependencies, then import them individually.